# Issue with STOMP on ActiveMQ being used on OSGI (KARAF)

Tags: activemq-classic, stomp, apache-karaf

I have installed Karaf (2.2.5) on Ubuntu Linux 10.04.
Installed ActiveMQ as a feature on top of Karaf.
Created a custom broker with stomp connector.
Now when I try to connect to this stomp broker from Java client, I get "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out"

The same client works fine if I start ActiveMQ as a stand alone application.

Thanks in Advance

Here's my config:

```
<beans
  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:amq="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:osgi="http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
  http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd   
  http://activemq.apache.org/camel/schema/spring http://activemq.apache.org/camel/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi/spring-osgi.xsd">
    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"/>
    <broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" brokerName="dios" dataDirectory="${karaf.data}/activemq/dios" useShutdownHook="false">
        <destinationPolicy>
            <policyMap>
              <policyEntries>
                <policyEntry topic=">" producerFlowControl="true" memoryLimit="1mb">
                  <pendingSubscriberPolicy>
                    <vmCursor />
                  </pendingSubscriberPolicy>
                </policyEntry>
                <policyEntry queue=">" producerFlowControl="true" memoryLimit="1mb">
                </policyEntry>
              </policyEntries>
            </policyMap>
        </destinationPolicy> 
        <managementContext>
            <managementContext createConnector="false"/>
        </managementContext>
        <persistenceAdapter>
            <kahaDB directory="${karaf.data}/activemq/dios/kahadb"/>
        </persistenceAdapter>
        <shutdownHooks>
           <bean xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" id="hook" class="org.apache.activemq.hooks.SpringContextHook" />
        </shutdownHooks>
        <transportConnectors>
            <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616"/>
            <transportConnector name="stomp" uri="stomp://0.0.0.0:61613?trace=true"/>
        </transportConnectors>
    </broker>
    <bean id="activemqConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
        <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="pooledConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory">
        <property name="maxConnections" value="8" />
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="activemqConnectionFactory" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="resourceManager" class="org.apache.activemq.pool.ActiveMQResourceManager" init-method="recoverResource">
          <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
          <property name="connectionFactory" ref="activemqConnectionFactory" />
          <property name="resourceName" value="activemq.dios" />
    </bean>
    <osgi:reference id="transactionManager" interface="javax.transaction.TransactionManager" />
    <osgi:service ref="pooledConnectionFactory">
        <osgi:interfaces>
            <value>javax.jms.ConnectionFactory</value>
        </osgi:interfaces>
        <osgi:service-properties>
            <entry key="name" value="dios"/>
        </osgi:service-properties>
    </osgi:service>
</beans>
```

Comment: Can anyone please help?? I'm stuck here!!

Comment: Can you put your broker configuration here? People can't help if they don't understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see an obvious problem with your config... Personally, I've stopped using Spring in OSGi because I kept encountering boot-time race conditions. Spring's `<osgi:service>` uses timeouts, so a delay in booting messes everything up. The following alternative approach has worked very well for me under Karaf 2.2.4:

- Add this repo to my etc/org.apache.karaf.features.cfg file: `mvn:org.apache.activemq/activemq-karaf/${activemq.version}/xml/features`
- Add an etc/activemq-broker.xml file written via Blueprint. I started with [an example XML from Talend](https://github.com/Talend/tsf/blob/master/talend-sf/src/main/distribution/text/container/etc/activemq-broker.xml) and customized it to my needs.
- Declare a dependency on activemq-blueprint in my own features.xml file like so: `<feature version="${activemq.version}">activemq-blueprint</feature>`
- Declare that XML file in my features.xml: `<bundle>blueprint:file:etc/activemq-broker.xml</bundle>`

I'm not a big fan of Blueprint in general, but it made this configuration really easy for me.